# Emacs lsp-metals: How can I setup java(JVM) opts for metals server?

Tags: java, scala, emacs, language-server-protocol

I'm developing Scala with Emacs, using [`lsp-metals`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-metals). It spawns metals LSP server (is scala program running under JVM) and interacts to Emacs.

When I coding, I found metals using memory with no limit (running with no `-mX` option). Sometimes I ended up lacking of memory.

How can I config java running option (`JAVA_OPTS`) for metals? I saw code for `lsp-emacs` byt I couldn't find reasonable config.

Comment: `setenv` should work and let you set any environment variable to a child process. Note: not all JDKs are handling JAVA_OPTS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS